# graphviz' dijkstra tool not considering edge weights

Tags: graphviz, dijkstra, dot

I want to use the dijkstra-tool coming with the graphviz package to calculate the shortest path in a directed graph with positive (including 0) edge weights.
But it seams that it does not consider the edge weights.
I call it like this:

```
dijkstra -dp "Start Node" graph.dot > results.dot
```

graph.dot contains:

```
digraph{
"Start Node" -> "B" [len=0];
"B" -> "A" [len=5];
...
```

results.dot contains:

```
digraph {
    graph [maxdist=385.000];
    "12_nach_48_1_1"         [dist=40.000,
        prev="12_von_69_1_1"];
    "12_nach_69_0_1"         [dist=43.000,
        prev="12_von_48_0_1"];
...
```

Comment: Please give all the input & output

Comment: Why the `...`? Provide a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the script producing my .dot file.
dijkstra did everything as it should.